# Can xlsxwriter open a .xls file and save it as .xlsx file?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I think xlsxwriter can opening or creating .xlsx file, and save as .xlsx format, but is it possible to open a .xls file and save it as the .xlsx format file?

Comment: What issue you are facing ?

Comment: Sorry, I want to use xlsxwriter to convert a .xls file (old Excel file format) to a .xlsx file (new Excel file format).